# How to get around the time gap in a comparison query that cannot repeat data?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using SQL in MS-Access and I'm stuck in a situation.
I created a query that fetches data from two different base spreadsheets and compares each code in them, to see if a certain code is in both spreadsheets or not. With this, two other spreadsheets are generated by MS-Access:

First generated spreadsheet: containing ALL the product codes in base spreadsheet 1 and comparing if it exists in base spreadsheet 2.

Second generated spreadsheet: containing ALL the product codes in the base spreadsheet 2 and comparing if it exists in the base spreadsheet 1.

NOTE: if a respective code appear again in any of the base spreadsheet, it will be never repeated in the generated spreadsheets.

This was the query I used to generate the comparison:

```
    INSERT INTO 

         generatedSpreadsheet1 (cod_BASE1, cod_BASE2, BASE1, BASE2, actual_date)

    SELECT 

       basespreadsheet1.code AS cod_BASE1, basespreadsheet2.code AS cod_BASE2, 
       IIf(IsNull(basespreadsheet1.code),"******Not******","Yes") AS BASE1, 
       IIf(IsNull(basespreadsheet2.code,"******Not******","Yes") AS BASE2, 
       basespreadsheet1.actual_date

    FROM 

       basespreadsheet1 LEFT JOIN basespreadsheet2 
       ON basespreadsheet2.code = basespreadsheet1.code

    WHERE NOT EXISTS 

      (SELECT cod_BASE1 FROM generatedSpreadsheet1 
       WHERE generatedSpreadsheet1.cod_BASE1 = basespreadsheet1.code);
```

So far, everything is working perfectly, however, sometimes, a product that appeared in the base spreadsheet 1 may take a few hours to appear in the base spreadsheet 2, and with that, if I run the query again, the comparison sheets generated by my query would continue to show that a certain code is in one spreadsheet, but not in another, even though now, this especific code is in both of them.
How do I get around this time gap?

Comment: question needs to be edited for clarity.  I assume spreadsheet refers to access tables or maybe access queries rather than something like an excel spreadsheet.  Also the business rules will end up being important for Upserting

Comment: the problem is you are inserting when you need to Upsert.  Upsert means update if a record exists otherwise insert a new record.  avoiding duplicate records is handled naturally when you Upsert.  Access doesn't have a native Upsert but you can do it manually so look up Access and Upsert.  Note the "Insert into" at the top of the SQL.  it is inefficient, but you could simply slightly modify your query into an update query and run the update query after the insert query.  however this quick fix doesn't remove the null rows.

Comment: spreadsheet in my question really refer to excel spreedsheets. My access takes data from two excel spreadsheets and, after the code comparison queries, generates two excel spreadsheets with that comparasion.